# spotifyd, cross compiling for arm64

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, compilation, arm64

I am trying to compile spotifyd for my aarch64 architecture using `cargo build --release --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`, all dependencies are installed and so far, compilation works.

However, the final step (`Compiling spotifyd v0.1.1 (file:///home/ubuntu/spotifyd)`) fails with:

```
 = note: aarch64-linux-gnu-ld.gold: -Wl,--as-needed: unknown option
          aarch64-linux-gnu-ld.gold: use the --help option for usage information
```

My configuration for cargo is setup to use the aarch64 linker:

```
/root/.cargo/config

[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "aarch64-linux-gnu-ld.gold"
```

It seems that `-Wl` is not available within `aarch64-linux-gnu-ld.gold`, are there any alternatives to `aarch64-linux-gnu-ld.gold` that I could use or is it possible to remove the `-Wl` flag from cargo?

Thanks for your advise.

Comment: `amd64` or `arm64` now? Also, passing `-Wl,xyz` to the linker seems odd to me, since that flag usually means "forward xyz to the linker"...

Comment: arm64, -wl seems to be passed by cargo automatically ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linker does not accept "-Wl" as an option, it is a command line parameter for the gcc Compiler Driver.

Gcc uses this option to pass command line parameters to the Linker, which the driver, gcc, will call if it's fed .o (object) files.

See gcc Docs [3.14 Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

> -Wl,option
>
> Pass option as an option to the linker. If option contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.

See any of these explanations (just skip to the bottom):

The Gentoo Wiki, "[Project: Quality Assurance/As-needed](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Quality_Assurance/As-needed#How_to_use_--as-needed)" in section "Failure in compile, unrecognized option".

Be aware of the version of Binutils Gold Linker being used, see [Bug 18859](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18859) as an example. Always check Bug Reports, but a bug is not the problem.

To directly answer your last question "Can I remove -Wl from cargo", yes you can but it's the wrong thing to do; that command strips unused code.

This option allows the linker to ignore, i.e., not link against, some of the libraries supplied on its command line if they are not actually used by the shared library that is being created.

What you want to do is change the linker to aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc and linking should work. See martinhath's question on Reddit "[Cross-compiling and linker flags](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/79vetn/crosscompiling_and_linker_flags/)".

So what you want is this:

> /root/.cargo/config
>
> [target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
>
> linker = "aarch64-linux-gnu-**gcc**"

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for your work and digging in here! I will try that of course!

Comment: No problem. If you want you can dig through the .configure files to find where the Linker is detected and determine why it chose to call the Linker directly rather than the Compiler Driver - usually extended detection routines would be utilized to detect specific features of specific Linkers, having done that subsequent Scripts should be adjusted to conform with the method. It's a Bug in the Configuration but not one that would harm your computer or program (once that script is edited). Filing a Bug Report at the email address or website provided in the Docs is the way to go.

Comment: I'm struggling with another issue (libasound) now, however, your answer is the correct one for this question. Thanks so much!